# Modify document.cookie in Chrome console not working

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Can I modify document.cookie in the console of Chrome Developer Tools?

My current cookie string was like:

```
"coldcookie="
```

It seems it just doesn't work if I run this code below:

```
document.cookie = document.cookie + "; newcookie=something"
```

The document.cookie wouldn't change at all.

**Update**: I found that if I run:

```
document.cookie = "newcookie"
```

It actually add a "newcookie" in the cookie string like:

```
"oldcookie=; newcookie"
```

Shouldn't that clear the current cookie string?

It does the same thing in IE. So I think there must be some rule there. Any ideas?

Comment: [Read the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie). You cannot just clear the cookie string. You can only set its expire time to the past to remove the effect of the cookie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cookies are set to expire, since we can't really "delete" them, we just force them to expire with a past date.

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 05 Oct 1990 00:00:01 GMT;';
};

deleteCookie('newcookie')
```

Comment: You can also append "...;domain=example.com;path=/mypath/"